# How to have a Lua iterator return a C struct?

Tags: c++, lua

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++03 project using Lua 5.2.1 where I would like to have an iterator return an object such that I can get parameter values or call related functions.
For example:

```
for f in foo.list() do
    if f:bar() then
        print("success")
    else
        print("failed")
    end
    print(string.format( "%d: %s", f.id, f.name))
end
```

I am using the following C++ code to implement this (error checking omitted):

```
struct Foo {
    int id;
    char name[ 256 ];
    HANDLE foo_handle;
}

int foo_list( lua_State* L )
{
    Foo* f = ( Foo* )lua_newuserdata( L, sizeof( Foo ) );
    ZeroMemory( f, sizeof( Foo ) );
    luaL_getmetatable( L, foo_metatable );
    lua_setmetatable( L, -2 );
    f->foo_handle = CreateFooHandle();
    lua_pushcclosure( L, foo_iter, 1 );
    return 1;
}

int foo_iter( lua_State* L )
{
    Foo* foo = ( Foo* )lua_touserdata( L, lua_upvalueindex( 1 ) );
    if( GetNextFoo( foo ) ) /*sets the id and name parameters*/
    {
        // is this correct? I need to return some object...
        luaL_getmetatable( L, foo_metatable );
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int foo_name( lua_State* L )
{
    Foo* f = ( Foo* )luaL_checkudata( L, 1, foo_metatable );
    lua_pushstring( L, f->name );
    return 1;
}

int foo_id( lua_State* L )
{
    Foo* f = ( Foo* )luaL_checkudata( L, 1, foo_metatable );
    lua_pushinteger( L, f->id );
    return 1;
}

int foo_bar( lua_State* L )
{
    Foo* f = ( Foo* )luaL_checkudata( L, 1, foo_metatable );
    if( FooBar( f ) )
        lua_pushboolean( L, true );
    else
        lua_pushboolean( L, false );
    return 1;
}

int foo_close( lua_State* L ) { /*omitted. this part works*/ }

extern "C" int luaopen_foo( lua_State* L )
{
    // how do I differentiate between a parameter get and a function call?
    const luaL_Reg foo_methods[] = { 
        { "name", foo_name },
        { "id", foo_id },
        { "bar", foo_bar },
        { "__gc", foo_close },
        { NULL, NULL }
    };
    luaL_newmetatable( L, foo_metatable );
    luaL_setfuncs( L, foo_methods, 0 );

    const luaL_Reg foo[] = { 
        { "list", foo_list }
        { NULL, NULL }
    };
    luaL_newlib( L, foo );

    return 1;
}
```

But, when I run this, I get the Lua error: `foo.lua:2: calling 'bar' on bad self`

I realize there are wrappers that may do this, but I would prefer to understand the underlying Lua mechanism before implementing any wrappers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a metatable from your iterator, not a `foo` instance.

More importantly, your metatable contains methods, but no metamethods. In particular, if you want `foo` method calls to resolve to the methods in your metatable, you'll need to set the `__index` metamethod.

I'd recommend learning how metatables work in Lua, very well, before implementing the same via the C API.

When you say `foo.id`, if `id` doesn't exist in `foo` (or `foo` is a userdata) and `foo` has a metatable with `__index` set, this will resolve to one of two things:

1. If `__index` is a function, that function will be called with a string `id` and `foo.id` resolves to whatever that function returns.
2. If `__index` is a table, the value stored in `rawget(__index, 'id')` so `foo.id` essentially resolve to `rawget(getmetatable(foo).__index, 'id').

So if you want to use `foo:id()`, you can create a generic `id` method foo's metatable that returns the value `self.id`.

If you want to use `foo.id`, you either need to change `foo` to a table and store `id` as part of it's state, or implement `__index` as a function where you do string compares and recognize that `id` should resolve to `self.id`.

---

Here's a modified, simplified version of your code which shows the `__index` metamethod working:

```
static int nextFooId = 0;
struct Foo {
   int id;
   char name[ 256 ];
};

static const char* foo_metatable = "foo";

int foo_iter( lua_State* L )
{
   if (++nextFooId >= 10)
      return 0;

   // create and initialize foo
   Foo* foo = ( Foo* )lua_newuserdata( L, sizeof( Foo ) );
   foo->id = nextFooId;
   sprintf(foo->name, "Foo %d", foo->id);

   // set metatable for foo
   luaL_getmetatable( L, foo_metatable );
   lua_setmetatable( L, -2 );
   return 1;
}


int foo_list( lua_State* L )
{
   lua_pushcclosure( L, foo_iter, 1 );
   return 1;
}

int foo_name( lua_State* L )
{
   Foo* f = ( Foo* )luaL_checkudata( L, 1, foo_metatable );
   lua_pushstring( L, f->name );
   return 1;
}

int foo_id( lua_State* L )
{
   Foo* f = ( Foo* )luaL_checkudata( L, 1, foo_metatable );
   lua_pushinteger( L, f->id );
   return 1;
}

int foo_bar( lua_State* L )
{
   lua_pushboolean( L, rand()%2 );
   return 1;
}

int foo_close( lua_State* L ) { return 0;/*omitted. this part works*/ }

extern "C" int luaopen_foo( lua_State* L )
{
   const luaL_Reg foo_methods[] = { 
      { "name", foo_name },
      { "id", foo_id },
      { "bar", foo_bar },
      { "__gc", foo_close },
      { NULL, NULL }
   };
   luaL_newmetatable( L, foo_metatable );
   luaL_setfuncs( L, foo_methods, 0 );

   // copy the metatable to the top of the stack 
   // and set it as the __index value in the metatable
   lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
   lua_setfield( L, -2, "__index");

   const luaL_Reg foo[] = { 
      { "list", foo_list },
      { NULL, NULL },
   };
   luaL_newlib( L, foo );

   return 1;
}
```

A test:

```
foo = require 'foo'

for f in foo.list() do
   if f:bar() then
      print("success")
   else
      print("failed")
   end
   print(string.format( "%d: %s", f:id(), f:name()))
end
```

Output:

```
success
1: Foo 1
success
2: Foo 2
failed
3: Foo 3
failed
4: Foo 4
success
5: Foo 5
failed
6: Foo 6
failed
7: Foo 7
failed
8: Foo 8
failed
9: Foo 9
failed
10: Foo 10
```

Comment: In `foo_list` I set the metatable to be the an instance of Foo. Why is that not what I want to return? And if it's not what I want to return then what is?

Comment: Yes, but in your iter function you don't return that instance, you return only the metatable.

Comment: What does the `-2` in the line `lua_setmetatable( L, -2 );` point to on the stack? The lua_newuserdata()?

Comment: Yes, negative stack indices are counting down from the top of the stack. So first we create the userdata object, so it's on top of the stack (-1). Then we fetch the metatable, putting *it* on top of the stack and leaving the userdata just below it (-2).

Comment: I should mention that you were *already* doing that. The most significant change I made was to create an __index member of your metatable (without which all attempts to index a userdata will generate an error) and point it back to the metatable, so that method calls are resolved back into the metatable itself.